# ActiveMQ getClientId and removeinfo objectid don't match

Tags: java, activemq-classic

i have an ActiveMQ java client that needs to detect other client connect/disconnect events.
by subscribing to connection advisory topic that is provided by `AdvisorySupport.getConnectionAdvisoryTopic()`, i've noticed that i get different client/connection/removeinfo ids.

for example, calling `.getClientId()` directly on the connection object returns an id like this:

> ID:computername-60117-1388179017343-0:1

receiving the connection id via advisorySupport topic subscription, i see an id that is *almost* the same, like this:

> ID:computername-60117-1388179017343-1:1

(note second to last number is one greater)

finally, looking at the id returned by a disconnection event, via `removeInfo.getObjectId`, i also get an id like this:

> ID:computername-60117-1388179017343-1:1

so my question is: why are the ids in the messages received via advisorySupport topic subscriptions always one greater than the id returned by `connection.getClientId()`?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ do you use?

Comment: sorry, yeah, using ActiveMQ 5.8.

Comment: `clientId != connectionId`, where `clientId` can be set by peer: `ActiveMQConnectionFactory acf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(); acf.setClientId("MyId");`